# Can $\mu$-analysis apply to robust D-stability analysis?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, stability-theory, linear-control

The $\mu$-analysis is known to give the minimum norm of the uncertain diagonal matrix $\bf{\Delta}$ that cause the $\bf{M}$-$\bf{\Delta}$ system to be unstable.

[image: $\bf{M}$-$\bf{\Delta}$ system]

The above term "unstable" refers to the condition when at least one eigenvalue rests on the *right half plane*.

However, I am wondering if the concept of "stability" of $\mu$-analysis can be extended to D-stability?

Here D is a defined region in the complex plane, and "stable" is defined as the condition when all eigenvalues rest within D.

Comment: One 'cheap' way would be to find a rational conformal map that maps $D$ to the open left half plane.

Comment: It seems related to the circle criterion or popov criterion